# which one is more complex? calculating a 64 bits CRC or two 32 bits CRCs with different polynomials?

Tags: complexity-theory, fpga, crc

I was wondering how 64-bit CRC on an FPGA compares to two 32-bit CRCs (different polynomials) on the same FPGA. Would two 32 bits CRC be more complicated than performing a single 64-bit CRC? Is it going to take a while or it would be fast?

How can I calculate the complexity (or do a complexity analysis)?

any help would be much appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering how 64-bit CRC on an FPGA compares to two 32-bit CRCs (different polynomials) on the same FPGA.

On a "normal" FPGA it does not matter which kind of information (CRCs, checksums, floating-point values ...) you compare:

Checking if a 64-bit value equals another 64-bit value takes the same amount of resources (gates or time).

This is of course not true if you use an FPGA that has a built-in CRC unit that (as an example) supports CRC32 but not CRC64 ...

> Would two 32 bits CRC be more complicated than performing a single 64-bit CRC?

In both cases you'll need 64 logic cells (this means: 64 LUTs and 64 flip-flops).

In the case of a 64-bit CRC, 63 logic cells must be connected to the previous logic cell and there must be one signal line connecting the first and the last logic cell.

In the case of two 32-bit CRCs, 62 logic cells must be connected to the previous logic cell and there must be two signal lines connecting the first and the last logic cell of each CRC.

If you have an FPGA that allows connecting 64 cells in a row without using a "long" signal line, the 64-bit CRC saves one "long" signal line.

(**Edit**: On the FPGA on my eval board you can connect 16 cells in a row; on such an FPGA, both onw 64-bit CRC and two 32-bit CRC would cost 5 "long" signal lines.)

> Is it going to take a while or it would be fast?
>
> How can I calculate the complexity (or do a complexity analysis)?

You require one clock cycle per bit - in both cases.

Note that an FPGA works completely differently than a computer:

You typically don't need time to perform some operation but all operations are performed at the same time...

Comment: In other words, they are usually the same, but in some cases, it depends on the type of FPGA. correct? and do you know how to calculate CRC complexity? (or do you have any resources for that)

Comment: He gave you the complexity. In time, one cycle per message bit. In space, one flip-flop plus the associated look-up table per bit. That is with the least space and most time. You could come up with other implementations similar to those in software that could run in, say, eight bits per cycle, but take far more logic resources to implement 32 or 64 by 256 tables. In that case, it would still be about the same amount of logic for two different 32-bit CRC as one 64-bit CRC.

Comment: @MarkAdler So to make sure I need 64 clock cycles if I want to calculate two 32-bit CRCs. If it is FPGA or a normal computer what could be different? Thanks a lot

Comment: On an FPGA using shift registers, each 32-bit CRC would take 32 cycles. There's no reason that you can't calculate two of them at the same time with different sets of gates, _still_ taking only 32 cycles. Or a hundred of them, still taking 32 cycles. As I noted, you can reduce each 32-bit CRC to _four_ cycles, if you're willing to invest in a large look-up table on the FPGA, needing 8192 bits. Or two 32-bit CRCs in four cycles, with two 8192-bit tables.

Comment: The trades are the same on what you are calling a "normal" computer. You can do it a bit at a time, or a byte at a time with a table. There are more sophisticated schemes such as slicing-by-8 and interleaved for fewer cycles. However, the number of cycles it takes on a CPU depends strongly on the CPU implementation, especially the pipelining, branch prediction, and caching. There cannot be an answer to your question like "it would take 219 cycles".

Comment: On both FPGAs and on CPUs with multiple cores, there are parallel approaches that compute the CRC of separate chunks of data at the same time, and then combinging the CRCs. There is no limit to how much hardware could be dedicated to the calculation in order to reduce the time it takes.